# Find out if a time period matches the current time

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

I have a date like this:

```
 // just a example date
 $time_in_the_future_start = date('H:i', time()+60*60*24*7);
 $time_in_the_future_end = date('H:i', time()+60*60*24*7+480);

 $now = date('H:i', time());
```

How can I find out if the current time is within `$time_in_the_future`'s time?

For example if

```
$time_in_the_future_start = 21:30;
$time_in_the_future_end = 0:30;
```

and

```
$now = 22:07
```

it would be a match.

**edit:**
to clarify, the `$time_in_the_future` is a recurring event, with a date in the past or future. I only need the hours+minutes to match, not the rest of the date... Basically I just want to compare the time in a day

Comment: Can't you just get all three `time()` values then check if `$start <= $now && $end >= $now`?

Comment: according to your example: `start=21:30` and `end=00:30` are not times in same day. You should include days in this calculation, or simply just use function from my answer bellow. It doesn't care about date but still adds `+1 day` in calculation on `end<start`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### function inTimeRange()

I guess, this will work perfectly in your case.

```
  function inTimeRange($time_start, $time_end, $time_needle) {
    $res = false;
    $t1 = strtotime("1970-01-01 {$time_start}:00");
    $t2 = strtotime("1970-01-01 {$time_end}:00");
    $tn = strtotime("1970-01-01 {$time_needle}:00");
    if ($t1 >= $t2) $t2 = strtotime('+1 day', $t2);
    return ($tn >= $t1) && ($tn <= $t2); // or return ($tn > $t1) && ($tn < $t2);
    }

  var_dump(inTimeRange('21:30', '00:30', '22:07'));
```

### Output

> true

**Note:** All parameters must be in format `HH:MM`. You can pass `date("H:i", ...)` for parameters of this function.

Comment: The return should be return ($tn >= $t1) && ($tn <= $t2); to avoid a parse error

Comment: @ack yeah, that was typo. thanx.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `time()` part to retrieve a numeric value in seconds, which caters to using programmatically.

```
$time_in_the_future_start = time()+60*60*24*7;
$time_in_the_future_end = time()+60*60*24*7+480;

$now = time();

if($now >= $time_in_the_future_start && $time < $time_in_the_future_end) {
    // between times
}
```

and then to print the values with the hh:mm format, you can still use `date('H:i')` once you're done doing the check.

Comment: yes, but I only want to match the hour:minutes, not the day, month, year etc.. This date is recurring event, so I only need `H:i` for this

Comment: Oh, well in that case, I would look into `mktime`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example which compares the time in that day. Notice this will not compare the dates, just like you asked for.

This will convert the time into hours of that day so that we can compare it as one number.

```
$time_in_the_future_start = time()+60*60*24*7;
$time_in_the_future_start = date('H', $time_in_the_future_start) + (date('i', $time_in_the_future_start) / 60);
$time_in_the_future_start = time()+60*60*24*7+480;
$time_in_the_future_start = date('H', $time_in_the_future_start) + (date('i', $time_in_the_future_start) / 60);

$now = time();
$now = date('H', $now) + (date('i', $now) / 60);

if($now > $time_in_future_start && $now < $time_in_future_end){
  //withing time span
}else{
  //Not within time span
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the date, use `strtotime()` on both times to get the unix time stamp for each. Then check to see if the unix timestamp of the time you want to get is greater than the _start time and less than the _end time.

If they are all already in a timestamp form, it's even easier. Since it seems you are starting with `time()`, do something like

```
$start = time();

$time_in_the_future_start = $start + 60*60*24*7; 
$time_in_the_future_end = $start + 60*60*24*7+480;

$time_in_the_future_start_display = date('H:i', $start+60*60*24*7);
$time_in_the_future_end_display = date('H:i', $start+60*60*24*7+480);
```

then just do

```
$curtime = time();

if($curtime < $time_in_the_future_end && $curtime > $time_in_the_future_start)
    // Code here
```