# time difference calculating using php?

Tags: php

I find it difficult to calculate time difference using PHP. How to calculate time difference in `HH:MM:SS` format (hours:minutes:seconds) between two different dates?

For example, the input is:

```
$start_time : 19:30  
$end_time : 7:30,  
$currenttime = 21:30
```

I have to find out current time has match with given start time and end time.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759492/find-out-if-a-time-period-matches-the-current-time

Answer (score 1):

Convert the times to a timestamp value, which is an integer value in seconds. Then, you can subtract them easily to get the difference in seconds. After that, it's pretty straightforward to convert that back to hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$iStart = strtotime( '00:00:00' );
$iEnd = strtotime( '12:00:00' );

$iCurrent = strtotime( date('H:i:s') );

if( $iCurrent > $iStart && $iCurrent < $iEnd ) {
  echo "active!";
} else {
 echo "not active";
}
```

This will only respect the time (it will be active once a day).
If you need specific dates you can use:

```
$iStart = strtotime( '2012-12-01 00:00:00' );
$iEnd = strtotime( '2012-12-31 12:00:00' );

$iCurrent = time();

if( $iCurrent > $iStart && $iCurrent < $iEnd ) {
  echo "active!";
} else {
 echo "not active";
}
```